# Countable union of open sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

> Prove that if $A \subset \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}$, while $U_{\alpha}$ are open sets,
>
> then it is possible to have a countable union $\{U_{\alpha_{n}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, such that:  $A \subset \bigcup\limits_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_{\alpha_{n}}$.

Please any help or direction.

Comment: Hint: The topology on $\Bbb R^n$ has a countable basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix a countable basis $\{ B_k \mid k \in \mathbb N\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Fix $X \subseteq \mathbb N$ such that 
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{k \in X} B_k
$$
and such that for every $k \in X$ there is some $\alpha \in J$ with $B_k \subseteq U_\alpha$. (This is possible because $\bigcup_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}$ is open and $\{B_k \mid k \in \mathbb N\}$ is a basis.)

$X$, combined with a fixed well-order on $J$, induces a natural countable subset of $J$ as desired -- I'll leave it to you to figure out how.

Comment: Can you explain the end? It seems like the most difficult part.

Comment: @UmShmum Let, for $k \in \mathbb N$, $\alpha_k = \min \{ \alpha \in J \mid B_k \subseteq U_\alpha \}$. Then $\{\alpha_k \mid k \in \mathbb N \} \subseteq J$ works. Here the minimum is taken relative to some fixed well-order on $J$.